# Call python script from c# with images as arguments

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I have a c# application which have a bitmap object. I wish to call a python script and send him the bitmap.
The idea is to not save the bitmap on the hard drive because it will slow down the application. I wish to use the memory of the application directly.

Do you have an idea how I can do this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you know already how to pass a single byte? An array of bytes?

Comment: While saving it to the hard drive might "slow it down", you run the risk of corrupting the image (e.g. encoding loss) if passing it through as data in the arguments. There's also a limit on how large arguments can be, so there would be a limit to the size of files you can deal with. That might be OK for your use case if the images you're dealing with are small and simple, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution based on the idea of tdelaney. I use the standard input / output to communicate.

C#

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"test.jpg");

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\Python30\python.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "test.py", "");
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.Start();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush();
            p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();
        }

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Python :

```
import sys
import msvcrt
import os

msvcrt.setmode (sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
bitmap = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

output = open("/tmp/testpython.jpg","wb")
output.write(bitmap)
output.close()

print("hehe")

exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the python program to read the bitmap from stdin

```
import sys
bitmap = sys.stdin.read()
```

Have the C# program execute the program with `stdin` set to a pipe, write the bitmap and then close the pipe.

Comment: Excellent idea !